# How to use Jmeter's mail reader sampler to send/receive invitations and activation key in a Test plan

Tags: testing, jmeter, test-plan

I am creating a test plan to test mail functionality,
which requires to send 'Invitations' and 'Activation key' to other Email Id's form an application.

How can I implement Jmeter 'Mail reader sampler' to send the invitation and extract the activation key from it?

We use 'REST API's and Json.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [How to Create a JMeter Script to Check Email During Registration AND Grab the Confirmation URL](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-create-jmeter-script-check-email-during-registration-and-grab-confirmation-url) guide contains the answer.